# How to work with two or more seek bars on Android

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, seekbar

When I implement SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener I have method onProgressChanged (for example), which works with one SeekBar.

How can I get this to work with two or more SeekBars?

Specifically, this method:

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekbar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

}
```

Comment: what do you mean. Can't you add the listener to multiple bars?

Comment: Yes, how to add new listener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The firs argument of `onProgressChanged` is `seekbar` you can set this class for both two `seekbar` and then use method `getId()` to check wich seekbar called this method.

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekbar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
  switch(seekbar.getId()) {
    case R.id.simpleSeekBar1:
        // code block for first Seek bar 
        break;
    case R.id.simpleSeekBar2:
        // code block for second Seek bar 
        break;
    }
}


SeekBar simpleSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.simpleSeekBar1); // initiate the first Seek bar 
SeekBar simpleSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.simpleSeekBar2); // initiate the second Seek bar
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!